# Google Maps not centering on additional maps after expanding jQuery UI accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a Google Map inside a JavaScript Accordion UI, and it puts a pin in the passed latitude/longitude and "centers" on that pin.

For the first map, it works.  When you click either of the other two, it seems to put the (base of the) pin in the top-left corner of the map.  I'm already calling `resize`, as you can see in my code.

Here is a fiddle which demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/myingling/1c4bjsff/2/

I'm sure this is something simple, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the center of each map, then set it once the new accordion is activated (and that map has a size, when the map/accordion is hidden, it has a computed size of zero, so the marker is centered in the upper left hand corner of the div).

One option:

```
var maps = [];
jQuery("#accordion").accordion({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(maps[i], 'resize');
      maps[i].setCenter(maps[i]._center);
    } 
  } 
}).find('.map').each(function(i, o) {
  var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(
    jQuery(this).data("lat"), jQuery(this).data("long"));

  var map = new google.maps.Map(o, {
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD,
    center: latLong
  });
  maps.push(map);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLong,
    map: map,
    title: jQuery(this).data('time')
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.setCenter(latLong);
  map._center = latLong;
  jQuery(o).data('map', map);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wmh1towh/1/)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working great in the fiddle!  I don't know why it's not working on my server though, here: https://yt074.addons.la/tmp/track/list.php